# How to access a ssh server with a dynamic dns service?

Tags: ssh, dynamic-dns

Helo,

I was asked to sign up a dynamic dns service and give the address to a server administrator. He told me that he added my dynamic dns to the server so that I can ssh to the server, but didn't tell me the next step.

Give the fact that the dynamic dns name is test.testdns.com and he has added the dns to the server, What's the next?

1. Do I just ssh to the server normally? ssh username@serverip ?

or do I need to do it differently?

Comment: Does `ssh username@test.testdns.com` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH server is configured with the following option in the config file

```
AllowUsers root@test.testdns.com
```

You can login normally as you do for any other server. Using the DNS or IP of the server doesn't matter. It's the sshd that's resolving your dynamic dns host and allowing you access.

It's a good security measure but personally I don't use it as there is a third party involved in the login process.

Answer (score 0):

You use ssh to username@test.testdns.com. If you were asked to use dynamic DNS servuce, it usually means that server IP may change. If it happens, server registers in the dynamic DNS again, so that test.testdns.com always points to the actual server address.